# How to edit the footer panel existing in admin page of magento

Tags: magento-1.8, footer

I want to know that how can I edit the footer panel of admin page. I could not locate any answer for that. Please help

Comment: what you want to change.so that we can suggest you

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what are you trying to achieve, but the template used for the admin footer is `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/footer.phtml`.

If you want to change it, clone it inside a new admin theme and [change the admin theme](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/admin/using_custom_admin_theme_templates) to the one you create.

Comment: I place the page/footer.phtml customized file in my admin theme but on some admin page still use default admin footer.